# map resultset into complex json structure

Tags: java

I am developing an application using spring boot and MySQL. I am also using `JDBCTemplate` to interact with database from spring boot application.

In the specific case, I am calling a stored procedure which returns the resultset as like below:
(example data)

```
Cluster         AppType      Application
-----------------------------------------
C1               AT1            A
C1               AT1            B
C1               AT2            A
C1               AT2            B
```

I am mapping this result to pojo as like below:

**Repository:**

```
public List<UserSubHierarchy> getUserHierarchy() {
            List<UserSubHierarchy> listCount = new LinkedList<>();
            String sql = "   call GET_USER_SUBHIERARCHY()";

            listCount = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<UserSubHierarchy>(UserSubHierarchy.class));

            return listCount;
    }
```

**Pojo:**

```
public class UserSubHierarchy {
    private String apm_buisness_cluster;
    private String apm_application_type;
    private String apm_application_name;
     // setter and getter
}
```

After this I need to process the `List<UserSubHierarchy>` and bring the output as follows:

```
[
   {
      "text":"C1",
      "children":[
         {
            "text":"AT1",
            "children":[
               {
                  "text":"A",
                  "children":null
               },
               {
                  "text":"B",
                  "children":null
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "text":"AT2",
            "children":[
               {
                  "text":"A",
                  "children":null
               },
               {
                  "text":"B",
                  "children":null
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

For the above `JSON` format I have created pojo as like below:

```
public class AppList{
private String text;
private List<AppList> children;
//getter and setter
}
```

I have tried for last two days, I couldn't bring my expected output. Kindly help me or guide me to get the solution. I guess I am clearly mentioning all my resources, if not kindly let me know. Thanks all in Advance.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way using a mapping library because you want to change your structure from object to json in fairly convoluted fashion.  As far as I can tell, you'll have to do it manually.

Comment: Have you tried using GSON? It should be able to convert your `AppList` into the exact JSON you want.

Answer (score 0):

For collecting the items into a map structure you can do something like this:

```
final Map<String, Map<String, List<UserSubHierarchy>>> out = list.stream().collect(
          Collectors.groupingBy(UserSubHierarchy::getApm_buisness_cluster,
          Collectors.groupingBy(UserSubHierarchy::getApm_application_type)));
```

This gives back the following data:

```
{C1={
  AT1=[
    WIMdataReader$UserSubHierarchy@7a79be86, 
    WIMdataReader$UserSubHierarchy@34ce8af7], 
  AT2=[
    WIMdataReader$UserSubHierarchy@b684286, 
    WIMdataReader$UserSubHierarchy@880ec60]}}
```

If your data has a fixed structure like the data above then you can skip the children item labels and just have encode the map as it is, using whatever JSON library you prefer, giving output like this:

```
{  
   "C1":{  
      "AT1":[  
         "A",
         "B"
      ],
      "AT2":[  
         "A",
         "B"
      ]
   }
}
```

### Full test code

```
public class WIMdataReader {
  public static class UserSubHierarchy {
    private String buisnessCluster;
    private String applicationType;
    public String getBuisnessCluster() {
      return buisnessCluster;
    }
    public String getApplicationType() {
      return applicationType;
    }
    private String applicationName;
    public UserSubHierarchy(String buisnessCluster, String applicationType, String applicationName) {
      this.buisnessCluster = buisnessCluster;
      this.applicationType = applicationType;
      this.applicationName = applicationName;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return applicationName;
    }
  }
  private static final List<UserSubHierarchy> list = List.of(
      new UserSubHierarchy("C1", "AT1", "A"),
      new UserSubHierarchy("C1", "AT1", "B"),
      new UserSubHierarchy("C1", "AT2", "A"),
      new UserSubHierarchy("C1", "AT2", "B")
  );
  public static void main(final String... args) {
    final Map<String, Map<String, List<UserSubHierarchy>>> out =
        list.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(UserSubHierarchy::getBuisnessCluster,
            Collectors.groupingBy(UserSubHierarchy::getApplicationType)));
    System.out.println(out);
  }
}
```

Output: `{C1={AT1=[A, B], AT2=[A, B]}}`